# proper condition to check end of line in buffered reader

Tags: java, java-io

In below code, I feel while() condition may not be correct, because I am calling the readLine() method twice, means not verifying the firstLine string in my if() condition from reader.

what is the correct way to verify if buffered reader (br) has not reached end of line.

```
try {
    if (is != null) {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        os.write("x ample.abcd.com\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
        if (br != null) {
            while (br.readLine() != null) {
                String returnString = br.readLine();
                if (returnString.contains("250")) {
                    logger.debug(" string:" + returnString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)
            br.close();
        if (sockt != null)
            sockt.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It should be:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: means, we don't need to call again br.readLine()? inside while, it will already read the line and assign it to line variable?

Comment: the reason I changed the answer correct to is that while(true) is going to infinte looping, you condition in while is working perfectly in all the cases.

Comment: @mahesh It's not an infinite loop, because it has a `break`.  But some people don't like that kind of loop, and some people don't like `break`.  If you prefer the other style, that's fine.  I don't mind you changing your acceptance.  But the two examples do work exactly the same.

Comment: @ajb is right about this. The form I've given here used to be frowned on back in the 1980s when debuggers couldn't show you the assignment inside the 'while' condition. My own preference is for the least code.

Comment: @ajb, I don't know but when if condition does not meet at atll, it is not coming out of the while loop, but is working if just put readLine in the loop. I think it depends on stream of data?

Comment: @mahesh That would mean you have a file of infinite size.  Or a socket that doesn't know when it's reached the end.  But please note that the condition at which I break from the loop is **exactly** the same as for EJP's answer; both of them call `readLine()` and exit the loop when it returns null.  If `readLine()` never returns null, then both will loop infinitely.  The difference is _only_ a matter of style.

Comment: @ajb There is no such thing as 'a socket that doesn't know when it has reached its end'. It would mean he had a socket that is never closed by the peer.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that your code is calling `readLine()` twice.  It calls it once when it evaluates the `while` to see if the condition is true.  Then, if it's true, the next statement calls it again, which means the previous line is lost.

If the code in EJP's answer looks too complex or not readable enough, here's another way:

```
while (true) {
    String resultString = br.readLine();
    if (resultString == null)
        break;
    // ... the rest of the loop
}
```